# How to use range with mysql data seek

Tags: php, mysql

I realize i can use range in the query. Bt what if to dont wanna make another query? I only wanna sort my previous result set.

Is it possible to specify a range for mysql pointer while using mysql_data_seek()?

Eg.

```
 mysql_data_seek($result, 0-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

use range in the query.

syntax:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

example:

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE Price BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in php and not mysql?

Comment: <?php
$number = range(0,5);
print_r ($number);
?>    this will print the numbers in range 0-5

Comment: i think you can store the range in a variable like what i written in above comment => $range=range(0,5) and use that variable inside the =>mysql_data_seek($result, $range);

Comment: Storing as range, then using in data_seek gives error... mysql_data_seek() expects parameter 2 to be long, array given

Comment: then use a for loop before the mysql_data_seek

Comment: I also realise i can loop the result set. Wat i'm tryin to acheive is to get a certain range of the result set into an html table... there after be able to access that table with javascript. If i loop, wont knw the id of the html element to call from javascript because it will steroetype my id and names